# Exponentiation by squaring

Tags: java, algorithm, math

While i was searching for  [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) i got the recursive method there but then i stumbled upon this pseudo code , Which i'm unable to understand fully.

```
function powermod(base, exponent, modulus) {
    if (base < 1 || exponent < 0 || modulus < 1)
        return -1

    result = 1;
    while (exponent > 0) {
       if ((exponent % 2) == 1) {
           result = (result * base) % modulus;
       }
       base = (base * base) % modulus;
       exponent = floor(exponent / 2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

if you can give some insight in simple terms it will be of great help

Comment: it is exponentiation-by-squaring for modular arithmetic, i.e compute `base^exponent mod modulus` using repeated squaring

Comment: Why there is odd check of the exponent ?

Comment: the odd check is there because the exponent might not be an even number (exactly divisable by two), so the remaining should be added extra

Comment: It should be `if (base < 0n`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code relies on the fact that:

```
x^y == (x*x)^(y/2)
```

The loop is doing exactly that: dividing the exponent by two while squaring the base.

**An example:**

Let's consider computing the result of 3^13. You can write the exponent (13) as a sum of binary powers: `3^(8+4+1)`. Then: `3^13 = 3^8 * 3^4 * 3^1`.

This decomposition in binary powers is done by the `%2`, `/2` done in the code, using the rationale exponained above.

**Step by step:**

You start with `3^13`. As `13%2==1`, you multiply the result by `3`, because the answer **does** have a factor `3^1`.

Then you divide the exponent by 2 and square the base (`9^6 == 3^12`). As `6%2==0`, this means the answer **doesn't** have a factor `3^2`.

Then you divide the exponent by 2 and square the base (`81^3 == 3^12`). As `3%2==1`, you multiply the result by 81 because the answer **does** have a factor `3^4`.

Then you divide the exponent by 2 and square the base (`6561^1 == 3^8`). As `1%2==1`, you multiply the result by 6561 because the answer **does** have a factor `3^8`.

Comment: Why there is odd check of the exponent ?

Answer (score 3):

Assume you want to calculate x^y with y in Z. Note y=y/2+y%2 (using "/" as integer division an "%" as modulus).

```
a) if y == 0 then x^y=1; if y==1 then x^y=x; if y==-1 then x^y=1/x.

b) If y%2 == 0 then x^y = (x^2)^(y/2) => square x (x'=x^2), divide y by two (y'=y/2), and apply recursively the algorithm to calculate x'^y' = x^y.

c) If y%2 == 1 then x^y = (x^2)*((x^2)^(y/2)) => square x (x'=x^2), divide y by two (y'=y/2), and apply recursively the algorithm to calculate x'^y', and after x^y = x'*(x'^y').
```

In this way, using only integer division and square of values you can calculate any exponential.

Example: x^19

```
1) 19%2==1 [rule c] => x^19=x'*(x'^9) where x' = x^2.
2) 9%2==1 [rule c] => x'^9=x''*(x''^4) where x'' = x'^2.
3) 4%2==0 [rule b] => x''^4=x'''^2 where x''' = x''^2.
4) 2%2==0 [rule b] => x'''^2 = x''''^1 where x''''=x'''^2.
5) x''''^1 [rule a] is immediate.
```

if the calculus is done over a finite field of integers mod n, the logic is the same.

**Addendum**

In fact, same logic can be used to the more simple calculus and more easy to understand problem of a number multiplied by an integer: x*y.

```
a) if y == 0 then x*y=0; if y==1 then x*y=x; if y==-1 then x*y=-x.

b) If y%2 == 0 then x*y = (x*2)*(y/2) => multiply x by 2 (x'=x*2), divide y by two (y'=y/2), and apply recursively the algorithm to calculate x'*y' = x*y.

c) If y%2 == 1 then x*y = (x*2)+(x*2)*(y/2) => multiply x (x'=x*2), divide y by two (y'=y/2), apply recursively the algorithm to calculate x'*y', and after x*y = x'+x'*y'.
```

int way, product is reduced to addition and shift operations.

Comment: Thank you for the rules!

Answer (score -3):

here:

```
public class maths 
{

    private float Base;
    private float Exponent;
    private float Modulus;
    private float Result;


    public float powermod(float base, float exponent, float modulus) 
    {
        if (base < 1 || exponent < 0 || modulus < 1)
        {
            return -1;
        }



        while (exponent > 0) 
        {
           if ((exponent % 2) == 1) 
           {
               Result = (Result * base) % modulus;
           }

        base = (base * base) % modulus;
        exponent = floor(exponent / 2);
        }
        return Result;
    } 


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        maths m = new maths();
       System.out.println( m.powermod(0, 1, 2));
       System.out.println( m.powermod(1, 2, 3));
        System.out.println(m.powermod(3, 3, 3));
        System.out.println(m.powermod(4, 4, 4));


    }

}
```

Comment: This is not the answer just a implementation which OP is not seeking !