# Explain this Power Mod B ^ E mod M bruteforce algorithm in MIT open courseware

Tags: algorithm, integer, modulo

I came across this algorithm to do (B^E) mod M in MIT's 6.006 course,

Can you explain the logic step by step, I don't get the part where they iterate 1 to 8

```
POWMOD(B, E, M, N)
1 R = ONE(N) // result
2 X = COPY(B, N) // multiplier
3 for i = 1 to N
4     mask = 1
5     for bit = 1 to 8
6         if E[i] & mask != 0
7             R = MOD(MULTIPLY(R, X, N), M, 2N)
8         X = MOD(MULTIPLY(X, X, N), M, 2N)
9         mask = LSB(mask · 2)
10 return R
```

Here is link to actual problem set

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-006-introduction-to-algorithms-fall-2011/assignments/MIT6_006F11_ps5.pdf

Comment: Do you understand what `B` and `E` are, and how they are represented in memory? Once you've got that, the algorithm is "exponentiation by squaring", which is explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694842/exponentiation-by-squaring

Comment: Thanks, I got how it works after little thought , I was actually confused by mask, Now I understand that it is used for checking each bit of word E[i] is not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is modulo exponentiation by squaring algorithm as pointed out by Paul Hankin.

We first iterate each word/ byte  in E  ( E[i] has 8 bits , and E is N bytes long)

For each bit in the current byte, we start iterating on the bits in the byte, this is done using mask variable, mask is intially set to one, so bitwise AND of  E[1] , 0000001 basically checks wether last bit(LSB) of the word is 1 , Each iteration, we shift mask to left by simply multiplying by 2. ie for bit=2 mask is 00000010 , and so on till mask becomes 100000000

We keep squaring (with modulo) on X , so for each bit in E, we have X value to be  B, B^2, B^4, B^8

We keep multiply (with mod) current value of X with result if the bit on E is 1.

So for example to compute B ^ (00000011) % M

we simply compute ((B % M) * (B ^ 2) % M) % M